# How to specify filters for Azure Compute's C# client?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-management-api, azure-rest-api

I am trying to use `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute`'s `ComputeManagementClient` to query for [ResourceSKUs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list?source=docs). But I am unable to provide the correct value for the filter parameter. Without a filter, the response is pretty large, and I want to reduce it by filtering with resourceType = virtualMachines.

More specifically this is my code:

```cs
ComputeManagementClient computeManagementClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credentials);
computeManagementClient.SubscriptionId = "**********";
string filter = "resourceType eq 'virtualMachines'";  // Doesn't work. All results are returned.
// string filter = "$filter=resourceType eq 'virtualMachines'";  // Doesn't work. All results are returned.
// string filter = "resourceType eq virtualMachines";  // Doesn't work. All results are returned.
// string filter = "resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'";  // Doesn't work. All results are returned.
// string filter = "resourceType = 'virtualMachines'";  // Doesn't work. All results are returned.
// string filter = "resourceType='virtualMachines'";  // Doesn't work. All results are returned.
IPage<ResourceSku> resourceSkus = await computeManagementClient.ResourceSkus.ListAsync(filter: filter);
```

I also tried using `OData.FilterString.Generate` to [generate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.rest.azure.odata.filterstring.generate?view=azure-dotnet) the filter string:

```cs
Expression<Func<ResourceSku, bool>> filterPredicate = x => x.ResourceType.Equals("virtualMachines", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
string filter = FilterString.Generate(filterPredicate);
IPage<ResourceSku> resourceSkus = await computeManagementClient.ResourceSkus.ListAsync(filter: filter);
```

Any idea what is the correct format?

Comment: Have you referred to  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/6393#issuecomment-559314469

Comment: Thanks! It sounds like they only support filter by location parameter for now.

Comment: I think so. The [Azure feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/37154362-impossible-to-filter-the-azure-rest-api-sku-inform) says that the api  only supports filter by location

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept the answer? It may help more people.

Comment: Update: I filed this as a bug on [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/9428). It's now marked as closed mentioning this is a feature request. If you would like this supported, upvote the feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/39435124-add-additional-filter-options-to-compute-resource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, the ResourceSkus API just support filter by region. For more details, please refer to the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/37154362-impossible-to-filter-the-azure-rest-api-sku-inform) and the [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/6393#issuecomment-559314469)